# How to vary levels of authorization(permissions) in node js

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, express, authorization

I am creating a basic business web app that should have two levels of authorization. I don't just want to protect API endpoints, though. I want different level users to see different pages on the same url. So for example an admin sees two buttons on the home page, whereas a sales rep only sees one button, as they shouldn't be allowed to access what is behind the second button.

What I would like to do is to create an "admin" boolean in my MySQL users table. The value of this field should somehow persist with the user once they have logged on. So if I am an admin and I log in, something like a session would carry the information that I am an admin, allowing me to check that piece of information in my AngularJS components, thus loading the correct templateUrl.

My component would have something like this at the top:

```
var tempUrl
if (user.admin) tempUrl = 'home-page/reports.template.html'
else tempUrl = 'home-page/reports-short.template.html'

angular.
  module('reports').
  component('reports', {
    templateUrl: tempUrl, ...
```

I am already using JWT's as a part of my own authentication scheme to protect my API endpoints and I would like to continue assigning one to every user who logs in, so as to protect all of my API endpoints.

I do not care if I violate any principles of REST, I just need a way to make the client hold onto information that I can later check on in my AngularJS components.

Comment: Are you using a templating library to render your pages? You could just set a JavaScript variable when you serve the HTML.
**Security Note** No matter how you solve the problem, you're going to want the security to be handled by the back end.  The front end should only be hiding things to aid the user experience.

Comment: I'm not using anything like jade/pug if that's what you mean. Everything is rendered using angular components, which have a templateUrl. The templates are just html files stored in the same folder as the components

Answer (score 0):

On the backend, you can have a table mapping each userId to a Role. If you are sure about having just two roles, could even use a bolean column, something like say `isAdmin`

So your user table would look like

```
UserId | isAdmin| other properties
1             true        Xyz
```

Further, upon every API call, you should do authorization just like you would be doing authentication.

Based on the authorization, the response would be different, which would help rendering components differently.

I would also strictly recemeded to have the entire authorization piece over the backend, and not do it over frontend